# Does Ruby on Rails lock user sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm coming from PHP background and have a question regarding RoR user sessions. By default PHP uses file storage with write locks for user session data. So it prevents processing of multiple requests by the same client at the same time. How does RoR behaves with sessions?

Comment: Why would you bother worrying about it? If it's actually an issue you can be sure a mature framework knows about it.

Comment: By default rails saves sessions in the users cookies, see the rails guides for more info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: @WaleedKhan I want to know if it's possible for impatient user to create a race condition in code that uses find_or_create_by_column where column is an unique index.

Comment: @WaleedKhan There is absolutely a race condition here, so this is definitely something worth "worrying about" (i.e. knowing about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default session store in rails store the entirety of the session data in the session cookie itself (known as the cookiestore).

One side effect of this is that if 2 overlapping requests both try and update the session then the last one to send a response back to the client 'wins'.

I don't think any of the session stores commonly in use with Rails have the concurrency property you describe.